# How to handle errors in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I want to make my django app as user friendly as possible and I want to handle appropriate errors and have it push out an error message sort of like an alert in javascript. I want to do this when there's no file uploaded. So when the upload button is pressed and nothing have been uploaded there would be an alert message sent out.

My view, `views.py`:

```
def upload(request):

    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, 'uploadpage/upload.html', {})

    else:
        excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]

        # you may put validations here to check extension or file size

        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)

        # getting a particular sheet by name out of many sheets
        worksheet = wb['Summary']

        # iterating over the rows and
        # getting value from each cell in row

        seller_info = []
        for cells in worksheet.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=5):
            for cell in cells:
                seller_info.append(str(cell.value))
        return render(request, 'uploadpage/upload.html', {"excel_data": seller_info})
```

My template, `uploadpage/upload.html`:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/upload.css' %}">
    <head>
        <div id='banner-container'>
        <div id='banner'>
            <h1 id='header'>MY APP</h1> 
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud" style="font-size:60px;color:lightblue;text-shadow:2px 2px 4px #000000;"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
        <body>
            <div id='upload-container' >
             <span><h1>Upload File !</h1></span>

             <span><h2>Upload Here</h2></span>

                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div id='input'>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="file" name="excel_file">
                        <div id='btn'><button type="submit">Upload File</button> </div>
                        </form>
                     <div>

            </div>
        </body>
        {{ excel_data }}
    </head>

</html>
```

Comment: What's your question? You've told us what you want but haven't told us what the issue is with the current code.

Comment: `request.FILES["excel_file"]` will throw an error if no file was added, you should use `request.FILES.get("excel_file")` and then test if this is `None`, in which case you'd render your page with an error message. I'd advise you to read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) and learn how to use Django forms to validate the input and display any errors to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django provided us [a message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/) which allow you to attach messages and then you can render it on your template by using `JavaScript` or simply just use django template.

My favorite library to show message on my web application is [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr). You can go to the document page to see how you will integrate into your project.

On your views:

```
from django.contrib import messages

# ...

def upload(request):

if "GET" == request.method:
    messages.error(request, "There's no file uploaded")
    return render(request, 'uploadpage/upload.html', {})

# ...
```

Then on your template you can use it like so:

```
...
<head>
    ...
    <link href="toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    ...

    <script src="toastr.min.js"></script>
    {% if messages %}
        <script>
            toastr.options = {
                "showDuration": "300",
                "hideDuration": "1000",
                "timeOut": "5000"
            }
            {% for message in messages %}
                toastr.{{ message.tags }}("{{ message }}");
            {% endfor %}
        </script>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

- `message.tags`: Using to match with the function of toastr, for example if you want to show an error by using `messages.error(...)` then the `message.tags` will be `error`, when your template rendered it turned to `toastr.error("Your message here")` and then you'll see the toast message on your browser.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to go about it:

1. You can create a client-side check that prevents the form from being sent with Javascript. That is not Django-specific and you'll have no trouble finding examples.
2. You catch the fact that no file was sent and set an extra flag for the `upload.html` template. Untested example code:

```py
    message = None
    data = None
    if request.FILES:
        data = # process file
        message = "Upload successful!"
    else:
        message = "Please upload a file!"
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {"data": data, "message": message})
```

Then you can show the `message` in the template:

```
{% if message %}
    <div class="message">{{message}}</div>
{% endif %}
```