# How to show a message dynamically in a django app?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I've created a webapp using django where in one of the section I asks for user's feedback and on clicking the submit button I send user an email thanking him for feedback.

But every time I click on submit, the page refreshes itself, the email get delivered successfully **But What I want is when user click on submit I want to show a "Thank you" message right there in place of feedback form. and feedback form to get removed**

Here's a section of my `index.html`

```
<form action="" method="POST">    
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>{{ form.message }}</div>
    <div>{{ form.email }}</div>
    <p class="formerrors" >{{ form.email.errors.as_text }}</p>
    <hr>
    <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

here's my view
def index(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FeedbackForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = "You got a message"
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        actual_message = "You got a message from {} \n\n {} \n\nGo to work\nWith regards".format(email,message)
        recipients = ['example@mail.com']
        sender = 'example@mail.com'
        send_mail(subject, actual_message, sender ,recipients,fail_silently=False)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('')
else:
    form = FeedbackForm()
return render(request,'my_webapp/index.html',{'form':form})
```

I can do this by writing a JS onClick function but is there any better way to do this? Also the built-in django messages refreshes the page I guess and are always on the top of the page. 
I certainly do not want my page to get refreshed and want message appear in place of form.

Comment: If you do not want your page to refresh, you need to use Ajax and on success, you can replace your form with Thank you message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send your form using [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). For the response part you could send a message from your server on successful validation and in your `complete` function of `AJAX` change the form's `display` property to `none` to remove it. Then create an element for your response message using `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

You could send your form with Ajax to your django view and replace your form with a thank you note  on the success callback.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the spoonfeeding thing. But can you please write a bit of the code because I've not used AJAX much. That'll be very helpful of you. And how can I pass my form using AJAX in a view. I've defined my form in `forms.py` and getting form in view from there only.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to use AJAX to achieve this. You could use [django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/) to create messages when user submitted their form.

Like so:

```py
from django.contrib import messages

...
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FeedbackForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
        messages.success("Thank you")

        # After submitted, redirect user to current page, the form will be reset
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
else:
    form = FeedbackForm()
return render(request,'my_webapp/index.html',{'form':form})
```

then on your template:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <p class="text-danger">{{ message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="POST">    
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>{{ form.message }}</div>
    <div>{{ form.email }}</div>
    <p class="formerrors" >{{ form.email.errors.as_text }}</p>
    <hr>
    <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Of if you want a toastr message?, reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994909/how-to-handle-errors-in-django/57995726#57995726)

Comment: Thanks for your response but as I said I don't want to refresh my page I just want thank you message to be displayed after submitting the form in place of form, here django messages will refresh the page. So is there any way to do this, I don't know much about AJAX if you could help me in that?